# \formatdate without day

Tags: datetime, date

I frequently use the `\formatdate{01}{02}{2016}` command to get a result like [image: 1st February, 2016]

Now I need the same thing, but without the day. I just need the month and year. Unfortunately, the `\formatdate` command only accepts 3 parameters.

Is there a command that does the above but only with month and year?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to switch to the new [`datetime2`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) package, which replaces `datetime`. This example also requires [`datetime2-english`](https://ctan.org/pkg/datetime2) as the `datetime2` language modules are distributed separately.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{showdayofmonth=false,monthyearsep={,\space}}

\begin{document}
\DTMdate{2016-02-01}. % not expandable

\DTMdisplaydate{2016}{2}{1}{-1}. % expandable

\end{document}
```

[image: February, 2016. February, 2016.]

You can localise `\DTMlangsetup`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{monthyearsep={,\space}}% global

\begin{document}
\section{Before}

Just using global setting.

\DTMdate{2016-02-01}.

\DTMdisplaydate{2016}{2}{1}{-1}.

\today.

\section{Scoped}

Localising one of the settings. The non-conflicting global settings
are still in place.

{% scope
  \DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{showdayofmonth=false}% local
  \DTMdate{2016-02-01}.

  \DTMdisplaydate{2016}{2}{1}{-1}.

  \today.
}

\section{After}

Just using global setting.

\DTMdate{2016-02-01}.

\DTMdisplaydate{2016}{2}{1}{-1}.

\today.
\end{document}
```

[image: Section 1 Before. Just using global setting. 1st February, 2016. 1st February, 2016. 22nd April, 2018. Section 2 Scoped. Localising one of the settings. The non-conflicting global settings are still in place. February, 2016. February, 2016. April, 2018. Section 3 After. Just using global setting. 1st February, 2016. 1st February, 2016. 22nd April, 2018.]

`\DTMdate` has a more convenient interface and is able to compute the day of week if the `calc` package option is used (which makes `datetime2.sty` automatically load `datetime2-calc.sty`), but it's robust and can't be used in an expandable context, such as writing information to an external file (e.g. the table of contents or bookmarks).

For example, if `\DTMdate{2016-02-01}` is used in a sectioning command (such as `\chapter` or `\section`) it will be written to the `.toc` file as `\DTMdate{2016-02-01}` not as `February, 2016` (or whatever the style format is at that point). This means that the date will appear in the table of contents in the style currently in effect when the `.toc` file is read by `\tableofcontents` whereas the section heading will use whatever style is in effect at that point.

Robust non-expandable material also can't be used in PDF bookmarks. The command will be discarded and you'll be left with just the argument.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{monthyearsep={,\space}}% global

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{showdayofmonth=false}
\section{\DTMdate{2016-02-01}}

\end{document}
```

This triggers the warning:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\DTMdate' on input line 11.
```

[image: image of document in PDF viewer]

The bookmark shows the section as "2016-02-01", the table of contents shows the section as "1st February, 2016" and the section header shows as "February, 2016".

If `\DTMdisplaydate` is used instead, the result is more consistent:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[en-GB]{datetime2}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{monthyearsep={,\space}}% global

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{showdayofmonth=false}
\section{\DTMdisplaydate{2016}{02}{01}{-1}}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document in PDF viewer]

The bookmarks, table of contents and section now all show the same "February, 2016", which is the style in effect when `\section` was used.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion using datetime. If I want to show the full date somewhere, how would I do that? Do I have to use \DTMlangsetup over and over again?

Comment: Also, what is the difference between expandable and not expandable?